# Numbers adder via generics

Tags: java, generics

This method add all numbers in list and return it as double

```
public HashMap<String, Double> add(HashMap<String, List<? extends Number>> map){
    HashMap<String, Double> result = new HashMap<>();

    map.forEach((key, value) -> {
        Double sum = 0.0;

        for (Number num : value){
            sum += num.doubleValue();
        }

        result.put(key, sum);
    });
    return result;
}
```

Testing my method with different types

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Adder adder  = new Adder();
    HashMap<String, List<? extends Number>> hashMap = new HashMap<>();

    List<Integer> list1 = new ArrayList<>();
    list1.add(1);
    list1.add(2);
    list1.add(3);

    List<BigDecimal> list2 = new ArrayList<>();
    list2.add(new BigDecimal("9.87654321e300"));
    list2.add(new BigDecimal("987654321"));
    list2.add(new BigDecimal("987654321"));


    hashMap.put("list1", list1);
    hashMap.put("list2", list2);

    System.out.println(adder.add(hashMap));


}
```

Is there way to improve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code is very inefficient:

```
    Double sum = 0.0;

    for (Number num : value){
        sum += num.doubleValue();
    }
```

It creates a `Double` object for `0.0`, and then, since `Double` objects are immutable, for every `num` in the `value` list, it creates yet another `Double` object for the resulting partial sum.  If you replaced `Double` with `double`, then you won't be creating new objects for each iteration through the loop.

---

Since you are already using the stream API, why not use [`DoubleStream::sum`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/DoubleStream.html#sum--) to sum the values as a `double`?

```
    double sum = value.stream().mapToDouble(Number::doubleValue).sum();
```

---

Finally, you could use the [`Collectors.toMap()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Function-) stream method to create the map.

```
public Map<String, Double> add(Map<String, List<? extends Number>> map) {
    return map.entrySet().stream()
          .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey,
                                    e -> e.getValue().stream()
                                              .mapToDouble(Number::doubleValue)
                                              .sum()));
}
```

Whether or not this last step is an "improvement" may be a matter of taste.

Note: the return type is no longer a `HashMap`; it just a `Map`.

---

The `add()` method doesn't depend on any members of `Adder`, so the method should be `static`.  Then you can get rid of the `Adder adder = new Adder()` object.

---

Using `List.of(...)` and `Map.of(...)` can simplify your test code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    List<Integer> list1 = List.of(1, 2, 3);
    List<BigDecimal> list2 = List.of(new BigDecimal("9.87654321e300"),
                                     new BigDecimal("987654321"),
                                     new BigDecimal("987654321"));

    Map<String, List<? extends Number>> hashMap = Map.of("list1", list1,
                                                         "list2", list2);

    System.out.println(Adder.add(hashMap));
}
```